# Laravel Save A Generated Pdf Inside A Queue

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a blade where I converts Html to a pdf and save it on my local , then I am using a live URL to get a pdf and save it on my local
Then I am using a laravel library to merge both pdf's and it will generate a single pdf by embedding,
It was working fine earlier, now I have a high-quality pdf where it takes much time to merge, due to it, it is taking some time and it returns a max limit memory issue,

so I tried to do it on Queue

this is my code

```
 $ecg_link = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/staging.uk-production.appspot.com/test1111.pdf';
    
 $ecg_pdf = isset($ecg_link) ?  $ecg_link : '';

 if($ecg_pdf){
        $ecg_contents = file_get_contents($ecg_link);
    
        if (!File::exists(storage_path('app/public/screening/pdf'))){
            File::makeDirectory(storage_path('app/public/screening/pdf'), 0777, true, true);
        }

        \Storage::disk('public')->put('screening/pdf/'.$screening_id.'.pdf', $ecg_contents);
      
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('participants.test', 
         compact('participantdata','Allopurinol','stn_assetreview'));

        if (!File::exists(storage_path('app/public/screening/pdf/temporary-pdf'))){
            File::makeDirectory(storage_path('app/public/screening/pdf/temporary-pdf'), 0777, 
        true, true);
        }
        $pdf->save(storage_path('app/public/screening/pdf/temporary-pdf/'.$screening_id.'.pdf'));

        $pdfMerger = PDFMerger::init(); //Initialize the merger
        $pdfMerger->addPDF(storage_path('app/public/screening/pdf/temporary-pdf/'.$screening_id.'.pdf'), 'all');
        $pdfMerger->addPDF(storage_path('app/public/screening/pdf/'.$screening_id.'.pdf'), 'all' );
       

        $pdfMerger->merge();

        if (!File::exists(storage_path('app/public/screening/pdf/final-pdf'))){
            File::makeDirectory(storage_path('app/public/screening/pdf/final-pdf'), 0777, true, true);
        }
        $pdfMerger->save($screening_id.'.pdf', "download");
```

when I use queue , I am unable to download the excel since its in the queue ,
I there any way I can download the excel,
else can I send this pdf over a mail?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a job, and whenever you save the data you can call `YourJob::dispatch()`

Comment: In that case you either should mail it or use supervisor which let the queue run when it’s hitting the queue